# OpenCV perspectiveTransform correct target width and height?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, geometry

I am currently working with OpenCV and its perspective transformation functions. I'd like to find a way to accurately determine the target rectangle based on the data (the source image) I have.
I already found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199116/perspective-transform-how-to-find-a-target-width-and-height
It states, that it is not possible to determine the correct aspect ratio correctly on the data contained in the source, but is there at least a good algorithm to get a good estimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do it from *just* the image alone. Imagine you were taking a picture of an A4 sheet of paper resting on a table, only you were looking at it near-on horizontal. If you used the aspect ratio from the image, you'd end up with a really long, thin rectangle.

However, if you *know* the pose of the camera relative to the target (ie rotation matrix) and the camera intrinsic parameters, then you can get the aspect ratio.

Have a look at [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/WhiteboardRectification.pdf) (it's actually really interesting, though the English isn't the best): equation (20) is the key one. Also, look at [this blog post](http://urbanar.blogspot.com/2011/05/aspect-ratio-of-rectangle-in.html) where someone's implemented the approach.

If you don't know the orientation of the camera then the best bet is to put in some sort of aspect ratio that is at least ballpark. If you have any other info about the rectangle, use that (for example if I was always taking photos of A[0,1,2,...] pieces of paper, these have a known fixed aspect ratio).

good luck!